# mapping nested Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hej guys

I have the following Object:

```
series:{
   Serie1:{
      subseries1:{
         a:a1,
         b:b2,
      },
      subseries2:{
         a:a1,
         b:b2,},
      },
   Serie2:{
      subseries1:{
         a:a1,
         b:b2,
      }
}
```

and I wanted to map this object so I would get an array like

```
[{subseries1}, {subseries2},{subseries1}]
```

I was using this map:

```
Object.keys(series).map(k => Object.keys(series[k]).map(key => k[key])
```

However this is not working at all what I intended to do. Any tips?

Comment: Hint: Loop over `Series<i>` and push processed values in an array. Concat output of current iteration with previous one. That should solve it

Comment: Can you correct the syntaxes first in `series`. `Serie1 ` seems to be an array but then you make it look like object

Answer (score 1):

unwrap first level SerieN values using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to merge and map over subseries
extract `[[key,value]...]` using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and map to individual objects

```js
data = {
  series: {
    Serie1: {
      subseries1: {
        a: 'a1',
        b: 'b2',
      },
      subseries2: {
        a: 'a1',
        b: 'b2',
      },
    },
    Serie2: {
      subseries1: {
        a: 'a1',
        b: 'b2',
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(
Object.values(data.series).flatMap(x=>Object.entries(x).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v})))
)
```